# Multilingual site title

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've got a problem translation my site title with the Configuration translation module. I set my set title to let's say XXX which is not displayed by the tamplte at all. Instead, it always attaches "| Drupal" string to the end of the node title.

When I click to add translation, translate the string to let's say YYY and save the form, everything appears to be saved correctly, the English version of my site even displays the correct title. However, the form for adding Site information translation still displays an "Add" button as if nothing had been added before and the default version of the site continues to display the "| Drupal" string even though my site name is set to XXX.

Has anybody else experienced the same behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have experienced a similar problem when manipulating with more language versions. In the `config` database table, I had two rows with the name `system.site` - one of them had a `collection = "language.sk"` and the other (full record) had an empty `collection` and in the `data` column `langcode` SK. So, I think the interface was confused, because there were two rows for one language. However, I do not know how the database got into this state.

So I have deleted the row with `collection = "language.sk"`, cleared the cache and now you can change source site name and also create translations - it started to work. Please try this and let me now, if that works.